# Quadratic objective with quadratic constraint with projection on a matrix

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, quadratic-programming

I have the following problem
$$
\max_x ~~ \sum_k | a^H_k B x |^2 \\
\text{s. t.} ~~ x^H B^H B x \leq c \\
$$
where $ x\in \mathbb{C}^N $, $ B \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times N} $, $ M > N $.

I know the problem is non-convex since the objective is a convex function. However, I would like to find a close-form solution for this problem. Is it possible? One idea is to use the Lagrangian although I may not attain a global optimum. However, even for this case, I am unable to go further. This is what I have thus far.

The Lagrangian is
$$
L(x,\lambda) = -\sum_k x^H B^H a_k a^H_k B x + \lambda (x^H B^H B x - c)
$$

The KKT conditions are:

(1): $ (\sum_k B^H a_k a^H_k B ) x = \lambda B^H B x $

(2): $ \lambda (x^H B^H B x - c) = 0 $

(3): $ \lambda \geq 0 $

(4): $ x^H B^H B x \leq c  $

Case I: When $ x^H B^H B x \leq c  $, then $ \lambda = 0 $ and $ ( \sum_k B^H a_k a^H_k B ) x = 0 $

Case II: When $ x^H B^H B x = c  $, then $ \lambda > 0 $. If we multiply by $ x^H $ at both sides of (1) then it yields $ \lambda \cdot c - x^H ( \sum_k B^H a_k a^H_k B ) x = 0 $.

Any hints how to proceed? Or do you see any alternative ways to approach the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The statement "I know the problem is..." does not make sense.

Comment: I meant that if it were convex I could have used CVX but I guess I messed up when writing...

Comment: You are trying to maximise a convex function, ironically that is not usually considered to be a convex problem.

Comment: Yes, that I have written above.

Comment: @copper.hat if you have any idea on how to address this nonconvex problem, please share it

Comment: I suspect it can be cast as an eigenvalue or SVD problem, it is $\max \{ x^* B^* (\sum_k a_k a_k^* ) B x | \|B x\| \le \sqrt{c} \}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\sum_k |a_k^* B x|^2 = \sum_k x^*B^* a_k a_k^* B x = x^* B^* (\sum_k a_ka_k^*)B x$, so the problem becomes
$\max \{  x^*B^* A B x  | \ \|Bx\| \le \sqrt{c} \} $ with $A=\sum_k a_ka_k^*$.

Let $Q$ be such that $Q^*Q = I$ and ${\cal R} Q = {\cal R}B$, then we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\max \{  x^*B^* A B x  | \ \|Bx\| \le \sqrt{c} \} &=& \max \{  w^* A w  | \ \|w\| \le \sqrt{c} , w \in {\cal R B}\} \\
&=& \max \{  w^* Q^*AQ w  | \ \|Qw\| \le \sqrt{c}\} \\
&=& \max \{  w^* Q^*AQ w  | \ \|w\| \le \sqrt{c}\} \\
&=& c\max \{  w^* Q^*AQ w  | \ \|w\| \le 1\} \\
&=& c \lambda_\max (Q^*AQ)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not understand the part where you say that RQ = RB. I can see that you defined a unitary matrix Q and that made w = Bx. But I cannot see the connection between Q and B.

Comment: $Q$ is an injective matrix with orthonormal columns whose span is the range space of $B$. For example, apply Gram Schmidt to the columns of $B$.

Comment: Ok, I see. Then to find Q, should I do SVD decomposition of B?

Comment: It really depends on what you are doing, you could use Gram Schmidt as I mentioned, QR would  be another approach. You could do SVD but it is more expensive.

Comment: Aha, thank you!